# Initial state in redux doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I want to show `<Alert />` component depends to state value `isVisible`. I set initial state but it doesn't work, although I see in `createLogger` that the status is changing. What am I doing wrong? 
I use combine reducers.

reducer_alert.js

```
const initialState = {
    isVisible: false
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_WEATHER:
            return { isVisible: false };
        case FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR: 
            return { isVisible: true };
        }
    return state;
}
```

index_reducer.js

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  weather: WeatherReducer,
  isVisible: AlertReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

weather_container.js

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.isVisible ? <Alert alertInfo="Sorry, but city not found." /> : null }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

actions.js

```
export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';
export const FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR = 'FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR';

export function fetchWeather (city) {
    const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city}`;
    const request = axios.get(url);

    return (dispatch) => {
        request
        .then(({data}) => {
            dispatch({type: FETCH_WEATHER, payload: data});
        })
        .catch((error) => { 
            dispatch({type: FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR, payload: error});
        });
    };
}
```

I can tell more, when I modify reducer alert like below everything works:

```
export default function (state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_WEATHER:
            return false;
        case FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR: 
            return true;
        }
    return state;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when you create a reducer like this :

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  weather: WeatherReducer,
  isVisible: AlertReducer
});
```

you will have a state that looks like :

```
state = {
    weather: ...,
    isVisible: ...
}
```

And by looking at your reducer initial state :

```
const initialState = {
    isVisible: false
}
```

you should access it this way : `state.isVisible.isVisible` inside your component, that's because your reducer is only responsible for `isvisible` part of the state (and not the entire state)

**TLDR**

Your first reducer returns an object : `{isVisible: false|true }`, so whenever you want to access the state, you should do it like this : `state.isVisible.isVisible`, while in your second example your reducer is returning a boolean `true|false`, that's why when accessing `state.isVisible` it works just fine.